# Dockerfile for Node.js with Python deploying to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile

I want to be able to run my app on the web. I am under impression as long as I use Docker on EB everything should run similar to localhost as long as all processes defined in Dockerfile. I like to use AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I am very new to this, and it EB with Docker seems to be very easy to get going and maintain. So far I got Node portion going. I just made zip file and uploaded/deployed on EB. But Python calls don’t work for 3rd party libraries i.e. I call .py file from route but it returns error because import didn’t work. It's my understanding that it's possible to have multi-stage Docker environment. i.e https://hub.docker.com/r/nikolaik/python-nodejs/. I understand general premise but can’t figure out how to adopt it for my case.
I tried to add Python portion to Dockerfile and load necessary libraries from requrements.txt. But now I can’t deploy on AWS EB.
Here is my docker file:

```
FROM python:3.7 as pyth
RUN mkdir /project
WORKDIR /project
COPY requirements.txt /project/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /project/

FROM node:8-alpine
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json* ./
RUN npm cache clean --force && npm install
COPY . /opt/app

ENV PORT 80
EXPOSE 80

COPY --from=pyth /project /opt/app
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't just copy the python files to the nodejs container cause you didn't install the requirements to the python in that container (if it even has python installed). You'd need to build an image that has both python and node available and requirements for both installed if you need to use both in your app

Comment: @Ngenator. I see. Thanks. Any suggestions on how to accomplish that in Dockerfile, if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already existing images that you can use that contains both dependencies installed. See https://hub.docker.com/r/nikolaik/python-nodejs/

Here is an untested example of how you can use it

```
FROM nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.7-nodejs8

RUN mkdir /project
WORKDIR /project
COPY requirements.txt /project/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm cache clean --force && npm install

COPY . /opt/app

ENV PORT 80
EXPOSE 80

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Note that you don't need a multistage Dockerfile.

If you want to go further and build your own image, take a look at this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/nikolaik/docker-python-nodejs/blob/master/Dockerfile) that is used to build the image in the example I gave.

Hope it helps

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you have any suggestions how to add selenium webdrives to the same Dockerfile?

Comment: No problem. You saved me hours if not more with your answer. Thanks again